# Trouble with Component placement with Groovy SwingBuilder

Tags: groovy

I am a Java developer and have done a fair share of GUI application building in Java. I am new to Groovy, and, quite frankly, I am confused over a few points.

My question is that I have the following code. And of all the constrains for Component placement, only the JButton.CENTER is honored. All the others are simply ignored. The top 'apanel' won't display unless I comment out all the code for bpanel. I've tried various other derivations for placement of Components and none work - some compile and error at runtime and some don't error at all - like these - but are not honored. Here is the code. Thank you very much in advance for any help. Also, for those that do GUI work in Groovy, do you use SwingBuilder, or do you code as you would in Java?

```
    import java.awt.*  
import javax.swing.*  
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder  
import java.awt.BorderLayout as BL  

name = "ATestGroovyGui"  
builder = new SwingBuilder().edt {  
    frame(title: name, show: true, pack: true, defaultCloseOperation:JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {  
        apanel  = panel() {  
            gridLayout(cols: 2, rows: 2)  
            label(text: "These", horizontalTextPosition: JLabel.CENTER)  
            label(text: "are", horizontalTextPosition: JLabel.CENTER)  
            label(text: "four", horizontalTextPosition: JLabel.CENTER)  
            label(text: "labels", horizontalTextPosition: JLabel.CENTER)  
            constraints: BL.CENTER  
        }  
        bpanel  = panel() {  
            borderLayout()  
            alabel  = label(text: "alabel",  
                 horizontalTextPosition: JLabel.CENTER,  
                 constraints: BorderLayout.WEST)  
            abutton = button(text: "abutton",  
                actionPerformed: { alabel.text = "changed" },  
                horizontalTextPosition: JButton.CENTER,  
                constraints: BorderLayout.EAST )  
            constraints: BL.SOUTH  
            println name + " button hit"  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Without assigning a layout to your `frame` `bpanel` basically sits on top of `apanel` which is the reason you cannot see it.

Comment: hsan, thank you for your response. I did solve this since, though I don't see off the top of my head how what I did made it work. I did, in the above, and have since done, set the constraints to BL.CENTER and BL.SOUTH. The only difference I can see is the way I did it. Now it is: `builder.panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER)` ... and same again for SOUTH. builder is, or course, a new SwingBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use Miglayout for any complex UI. There is a little bit learning curve but it will be much easier later. SwingBuilder support Miglayout nicely although there is not much documentation or examples available. I used to wrote [several posts about Miglayout and Swingbuilder here](https://sites.google.com/site/dracodoc/groovy/swingbuildermiglayout), you can have a look.